# Intuition about a matrix multiplication equality

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, symmetric-matrices, linear-regression

I encountered the following formula while studying the analytical solution of the Linear regression problem in Machine learning context (Optimizing the weight w.r.t squared error)

$w^{T}X^{T}y=y^{T}Xw$

$w$ is a vector of dimensions $D \times 1$
$y$ is a vector of dimensions $N \times 1$
$X$ is a matrix of dimensions $N \times D$

I understand that this equality holds for symmetric matrices, I also understand that the multiplication will result in a scalar, I am missing however why that scalar will be equal for both sides. A bit more intuition about that would be great.

Comment: A scalar is a symmetric matrix of order $1$ . What happens if we take the trasnspose of the expression in LHS ?

Comment: Aha I get it, can I conclude that "if a matrix multiplication results in a scalar then the transpose of this multiplication will always result in the same scalar" ?

Comment: Yes , you can conclude that.

Comment: Alternatively, you can think of the commutativity of the dot product: $w^T X^T y = w \cdot X^T y = X^T y \cdot w = y^T X w$.